# How to automatically create a new class variable when you call the same class everytime

Tags: python, class, variables

I want book1 to be created automatically without defining it, because this will be a while code so what I want to achieve is every time a user fill these inputs it creates book1 then book2, etc. and most importantly a way I can call them again

```
class Book(object): #this class stores books in detail
    def __init__(self, title: str , author: str, isbn: int, genre: str, numCopies: int):
        self._title: str = title
        self._author: str = author
        self._isbn: int = isbn
        self._genre: str = genre
        self._numCopies: int = numCopies



title = input("The Book's Title: ")
author = input("The Book's Author: ")
isbn = int(input("The Book's ISBN: "))
genre = input("The Book's Title: ")
numCopies = int(input("The Book's Copies: "))

book1 = Book(title,author,isbn,genre,numCopies)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when you have repetitive code, you can write a function for that.

This can be done in many ways. One of them is using a `classmethod` as another constructor for your class:

```py
class Book:  # this class stores books in detail
    def __init__(self, title: str, author: str, isbn: int, genre: str, numCopies: int):
        self._title = title
        self._author = author
        self._isbn = isbn
        self._genre = genre
        self._numCopies = numCopies

    @classmethod
    def from_user_input(cls):
        title = input("The Book's Title: ")
        author = input("The Book's Author: ")
        isbn = int(input("The Book's ISBN: "))
        genre = input("The Book's Title: ")
        numCopies = int(input("The Book's Copies: "))
        return cls(title, author, isbn, genre, numCopies)


book1 = Book.from_user_input()
```

You can then append the instances to a list/dictionary named `Books` for example.

**Note-1**: You don't need to inherit from `object` in Python 3.

**Note-2**: If you just created this class to hold data, take a look at [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple). It is much more lightweight.

**Note-3**: Although it's possible to type annotate variables inside your `__init__`, its useless in your case. For example `self._title` gets the value of `title` from parameters and you already defined `str` for that there. Its an unnecessary duplication. Static type-checkers can hint you from parameter itself.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and notes it's really helpfull. I just have a problem when I implement '''book1 = Book.from_user_input()''' it gives me an error : TypeError: Book.from_user_input() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @MoustafaAbouamer You're welcome. Are you sure you've copied the code as it is?

Comment: I am very sorry I think I messed up while writing it. I just copied it and it works. Thank you for your help <3